# Spring Security test session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-test

I am trying to write some tests for a practice project with spring security and I am using MockMvc and related classes to do so.

So my basic configuration looks like this:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

With tests similar to this one:

```
@Test
public void handleUserJSONRequest_shouldReturn401_withoutLoggedInUser() throws Exception{
    ResultActions action = mvc.perform(get("/userAsJSON"));

    int status = action.andReturn().getResponse().getStatus();
    assertTrue("expected status code = 401 ; current status code = " + status, status == 401);
}
```

What I still fail to achieve is to write a test to verify that my custom session-timeout is working.

I tried the following:

```
@Test
public void sessionTimeoutShouldInvalidateSession_withLoggedInUser() throws Exception{
    ResultActions action = mvc.perform(get("/userAsJSON").with(user("user")));
    MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession) action.andReturn().getRequest().getSession();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);

    ResultActions action2 = mvc.perform(get("/userAsJSON").session(session));
    int status2 = action2.andReturn().getResponse().getStatus();

    assertTrue("expected status code = 401 ; current status code = " + status2, status2 == 401);
}
```

But it will still return 200 (session timeout is set to 10 for testing purposes and can be verified to be working via curl); so I assume that has something to do with how MockMvc and MockHttpSession work.

Is there a way I can still test my session-timeout's functionality?

EDIT: On request -> my configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.sessionManagement()
            //number of concurrent sessions allowed for the same user
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .and()
            .sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession();
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(myRestAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secured")
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/userAsJSON")
                    .authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/unsecured")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(this::handleLogoutSuccess)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

with:

```
public void handleLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication){
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class MyRestAuthenticationEntryPoint
        implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide you spring-security configuration

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, unexpected vacation. Is that all you need?